# Can't deploy SharePoint MVC app to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, publish, azure-web-app-service, sharepoint-apps

I create provider-hosted app with Remote Event Receiver for SharePoint 2013 with Visual Studio 2013. Then I create simple Azure website to host my MVC App. So, when app deployed to SharePoint Online it could send events to the receiver.
Then I downloaded Publishing Profile from my Azure site and imported to my web deploy and publish my site.

When I open my site on Azure I get **"Unexpected error occurred"**.

When I publish other new/scarfolded MVC site It opens fine. Please suggest where to look or how to fix.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Azure responses with error every time calling SharePoint CSOM. I will have to start new thread for this problem.